# Unable to set Java Path in system variables (Windows 10)

Tags: java

I've tried adding JAVA_HOME with the directory - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121 to my system variables, and then adding %JAVA_HOME%/bin to Path variable and this didn't work and I receive

> 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

So I've tried adding C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121; directly to the path variable but I still get the above error. Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Thanks

PS - The image shows me in the command prompt at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121 trying 'java -version' - I just moved up one dir to test the variable, entering 'java -version' in the bin directory returns the correct info, as you would expect.

[image: Link to the image]

Comment: You can use the command `path` or slightly less convenient `set path` or `echo %path%` to see exactly is used in a given CMD. (You can also see other envvars with `set [prefix]`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try closing that command prompt and reopening it?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to reboot for any envvar change, even system=allusers; starting a new CMD should be sufficient and necessary.

Comment: @Dough it's okay, it happens.  You could not have known.  There exist silly questions on stackoverflow, this is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

In the command line,  run the following:

`set PATH=%PATH%:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin`

Without exiting the shell,  run your java commands

E.g.

`java -version`

This will surely work.